# Service keys with keyboard

Tags: c

I need help. I want using C to handle the keys. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do it. I care about formulating "if (pressed key == true)" something like that please help.

Comment: You didn't mention a platform: MSVC has the OS-specific `kbhit()` but there is no C standard function.

Comment: If you have POSIX, you could set non-canonical on your `termios`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a little bit more information cause your question doesn't contain enough?
If you're talking about checking the condition: does (pressed_key) exists or not, it's possible to write `if (pressed_key) //code` if it exists and some code after there. if it exists pressed_key will be equal to any number (except 0), if it doesn't exist it will be equal 0.

I don't know how to help you in other ways.(

Comment: I want to do something if a key is pressed it performs the task. It's just a reference to the fact I can handle it further.